# How can answers in ROBLOX Lua be scored?

Tags: discussion

I know scripting in [ROBLOX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roblox) is basically lua, but it adds a few elements. Those being a three-dimensional world and some kind of object orientation. Now, just for the sake of it, not to actually expect any kind of winning, I am planning to do answers using this. How exactly could you score these answers, assume there's more to it than just scripting? Should it be **required** to use script (Lua) only, and specify it as the RBX.Lua language?

Here's an example I quickly made, which utilizes two blocks that are **not written using Lua**, but placed in the world normally:
[image: Touching]

Now, using the ROBLOX Studio built-in feature to place bricks, this is possible in only 87 bytes:

```
script.Parent.Touched:connect(function()
    print("Hello World, I've been touched!")
end)
```

But when restricted to using Lua only, it totals up to 246 bytes best case:

```
Instance.new("Part", workspace).Position = Vector3.new(0, 5, 0)
Instance.new("Part", workspace).Position = Vector3.new(0, 5, 0)
script.Parent = workspace.Part
script.Parent.Touched:connect(function()
    print("Hello World, I've been touched!")
end)
```

Which of these two should be scored, and if it's the above, how do I handle the two parts in terms of bytes/characters/file size?

Comment: [related](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7377/programming-in-minecraft-redstone-how-to-measure-program-size) and [related](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10761/scoring-algodoo-and-other-physics-sims-with-logic-capability)

Answer (score 2):

If you use pure Lua count the size of the Lua (246 bytes in your exemple). If you use ROBLOX studio count the resulting file size, same as other "mixed" language such as algodoo or minecraft command blocks

Comment: While I agree on algodoo, there is now a unified measuring method for minecraft (http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9529/62824), so you cannot use that as a related question.

Comment: @devRicher While there is now a measuring method for minecraft, the past solution stay a related question, on wich the community agreed before structur block, as such i think it's relevant Roblox counting